# BASH print 2 files

Tags: bash, printf, cat

I want to print the output of file1 to first column in new file and file 2 to the second column in the new file.

Something like this.

```
file1  
AAA    
BBB  
CCC    

file2
XXX   
YYY   
ZZZ  

file3   
AAA   XXX
BBB   YYY
CCC   ZZZ
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

paste command will do this job out-of-the-box:

```
paste file1 file2 > file3
AAA     XXX   
BBB     YYY   
CCC     ZZZ
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910057/how-to-paste-columns-from-separate-files-using-bash)

You can use paste and format using cut to remove leading and trailing spaces

Comment: You should have shown command how to do that, or place this suggestion as a comment.