# Joining Columns on Command Line with Paste or PR Not Working

Tags: bash, cut, command-line-interface

So I have two files that I want to take columns out of and join them in a single file.

f1:

```
02/10/2013,16:00:00.091,123.82,OTCX,GLO,,123.82
02/10/2013,16:00:03.072,123.766,FXN,NAM,,123.766
02/10/2013,16:00:03.491,123.769,FXN,,,123.769
02/10/2013,16:00:03.565,123.79,COMM,ASI,HKG,123.79
02/10/2013,16:00:03.721,123.769,FXN,NAM,NYC,123.769
02/10/2013,16:00:04.194,123.81,AKM,EUR,MOW,123.81
02/10/2013,16:00:06.130,123.764,FXN,NAM,NYC,123.764
02/10/2013,16:00:06.330,123.764,FXN,,,123.764
02/10/2013,16:00:08.989,123.766,FXN,,,123.766
02/10/2013,16:00:09.034,123.791,FXN,,,123.791
```

f2:

```
02/10/2013,16:00:00.091,123.82,123.83,OTCX,GLO,
02/10/2013,16:00:03.072,123.766,123.888,FXN,NAM,
02/10/2013,16:00:03.491,123.769,123.888,FXN,,
02/10/2013,16:00:03.565,123.79,123.87,COMM,ASI,HKG
02/10/2013,16:00:03.721,123.769,123.891,FXN,NAM,NYC
02/10/2013,16:00:04.194,123.81,123.85,AKM,EUR,MOW
02/10/2013,16:00:06.130,123.764,123.891,FXN,NAM,NYC
02/10/2013,16:00:06.330,123.764,123.888,FXN,,
02/10/2013,16:00:08.989,123.766,123.886,FXN,,
02/10/2013,16:00:09.034,123.791,123.861,FXN,,
```

I saw the reference to a previous SO question here: [How to paste columns from separate files using bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910057/how-to-paste-columns-from-separate-files-using-bash)

but for some reason both the **paste** and the **pr** commands are not working for this data set: instead `paste -d <(cut -d "," -f 3,7 f1) <(cat f2)` just appends a comma to the front of every line of f2

```
,02/10/2013,16:00:00.091,123.82,123.83,OTCX,GLO,
,02/10/2013,16:00:03.072,123.766,123.888,FXN,NAM,
,02/10/2013,16:00:03.491,123.769,123.888,FXN,,
,02/10/2013,16:00:03.565,123.79,123.87,COMM,ASI,HKG
,02/10/2013,16:00:03.721,123.769,123.891,FXN,NAM,NYC
,02/10/2013,16:00:04.194,123.81,123.85,AKM,EUR,MOW
,02/10/2013,16:00:06.130,123.764,123.891,FXN,NAM,NYC
,02/10/2013,16:00:06.330,123.764,123.888,FXN,,
,02/10/2013,16:00:08.989,123.766,123.886,FXN,,
,02/10/2013,16:00:09.034,123.791,123.861,FXN,,
```

`pr -mts,` yields the same behavior as paste.

Any advice on why these files are behaving differently?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show a sample of your expected output?

Comment: Do the files have DOS-style line endings perchance?

Comment: Yes, thats definitely `CR` putting the cursor back at the start of the line overwriting whatever was printed by first file. Before running the command provided by @glennjackman below (which also fixes a bug you have in your command) do this - `tr -d "\\r" < f1 > tmp && mv tmp f1`

Comment: The final answer turned out to be CR, and found out through the 'file' command. Thanks to all of you guys for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you missed giving the `-d` option a value.

To put columns 3 and 7 at the beginning of "f2" lines, separated with a comma

```
paste -d, <(cut -d, -f 3,7 f1) f2
```

---

Accounting for CRLF line endings

```
paste -d, <(sed 's/\r$//' f1 | cut -d, -f 3,7) <(sed 's/\r$//' f2)
```

Comment: `<(cat f2)` is a useless use of cat.

Comment: +1 for fixing 3 issues!! UUoC, missing delimiter and identifying `CR`.

Comment: Thanks Glenn - I want to give you and jaypal credit, but your answer doesn't include the entire story (see my answer below) - if you want to modify your answer to include everything, ill accept yours.

Answer (score 0):

Combining the two answers (from jaypal's comments + glenn's answer) together, the final answer turned out to be, the CR end of line.

For a holistic answer, one way to diagnose this problem is

```
file filename
```

if it returns something like `ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators`, then you know that you have this problem. CR = '\r', LF = '\n', so in reality every line was terminating with '\r\n'.

Running `tr -d, "\r" < f1 > tmp && mv tmp f1` will delete all of the extra '\r' from the code and then allow paste to work as expected.