# How to Use Find - exec and Tr to process a large number of files

Tags: bash, find, exec, tr

I'm having a little trouble with find and exec in bash:

Suppose I have a bunch of files that I need to replace '\r' characters in. (previous question: [Joining Columns on Command Line with Paste or PR Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22722742/joining-columns-on-command-line-with-paste-or-pr-not-working?noredirect=1#comment34632490_22722742)) For each file, I want to read it, and replace all the '\r', and then write it back to the same file name:

The command I'm using is `find . -exec cat {} | tr -d "\r" > {} \;`, but I'm getting two errors:

```
tr: extra operand `;'
Only one string may be given when deleting without squeezing repeats.
Try `tr --help' for more information.
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

it seems like `tr` is interpreting ';' to be an argument, while `-exec` is not recognizing it. Is there a way to change this? I'm also creating {} as a file in the directory, instead of having {} being substituted for the file name.

I've also tried:

```
find . -exec cat {} | tr -d "\r" > "new_{}"; \;
```

but `"new_{}"` does not turn into `"new_filename"`, bash just takes it literally and creates a file called `"new{}"`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to redirect the output of a command used with `-exec`, you need to execute a shell command.  Moreover you'd need to redirect the output to a new file and move it back to the original filename.

Say:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'tr -d "\r" < "{}" > "{}".new && mv "{}".new "{}"' -- {} \;
```

An alternate would be to use `sed`:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/\r//' {} \;
```

or `dos2unix` (as pointed out by [kojiro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418413/kojiro)):

```
find . -type f -exec dos2unix {} \;
```

Comment: This seems to work, but when running file on the new file, it still says: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators, so it seems like it didn't replace the CR

Comment: @MaxSong The quoting in the first option was slightly wrong.  Should be fixed now.

Comment: Wonderful! Both commands work perfectly. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Probably worth pointing out that `dos2unix` will do an in-place overwrite for you, vastly simplifying the commands needed.

Comment: @kojiro Thanks, added that option.  I actually started by telling the OP of the _problem_ and the most obvious failed to occur!

Comment: If you're anal-retentive like me, you'd probably do something like `find . -type f -exec grep -qF $'\r' {} \; -exec dos2unix {} +` – this would avoid touching files that don't have to be touched.

Comment: Don't inject the filenames directly into the script. Pass them as argument(s). Instead of `-exec sh -c '..."{}"...' -- {} \;`, do: `-exec sh -c '..."$1"...' sh {} \;`

Comment: @devnull why this difference with respect to executing the command in a shell between tr and sed?