# Fast concatenation of thousands of files by columns

Tags: r, cbind

I am using `R` to cbind about ~11000 files using:

```
dat <- do.call('bind_cols',lapply(lfiles,read.delim))
```

which is unbelievably slow. I am using R because my downstream processing like creating plots etc is in R. What are some fast alternatives to concatenating thousands of files by columns?

I have three types of files for which I want this done. They look like this:

```
[centos@ip data]$ head C021_0011_001786_tumor_RNASeq.abundance.tsv
target_id   length  eff_length  est_counts  tpm
ENST00000619216.1   68  26.6432 10.9074 5.69241
ENST00000473358.1   712 525.473 0   0
ENST00000469289.1   535 348.721 0   0
ENST00000607096.1   138 15.8599 0   0
ENST00000417324.1   1187    1000.44 0.0673096   0.000935515
ENST00000461467.1   590 403.565 3.22654 0.11117
ENST00000335137.3   918 731.448 0   0
ENST00000466430.5   2748    2561.44 162.535 0.882322
ENST00000495576.1   1319    1132.44 0   0

[centos@ip data]$ head C021_0011_001786_tumor_RNASeq.rsem.genes.norm_counts.hugo.tab
gene_id C021_0011_001786_tumor_RNASeq
TSPAN6  1979.7185
TNMD    1.321
DPM1    1878.8831
SCYL3   452.0372
C1orf112    203.6125
FGR 494.049
CFH 509.8964
FUCA2   1821.6096
GCLC    1557.4431

[centos@ip data]$ head CPBT_0009_1_tumor_RNASeq.rsem.genes.norm_counts.tab
gene_id CPBT_0009_1_tumor_RNASeq
ENSG00000000003.14  2005.0934
ENSG00000000005.5   5.0934
ENSG00000000419.12  1100.1698
ENSG00000000457.13  2376.9100
ENSG00000000460.16  1536.5025
ENSG00000000938.12  443.1239
ENSG00000000971.15  1186.5365
ENSG00000001036.13  1091.6808
ENSG00000001084.10  1602.7165
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try profiling you code. Mt bet is that `read.delim` is your bottle neck. Try `data.table::fread` instead. Also Google regarding fast reading data sets into R

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697700/how-to-speed-up-rbind

Comment: Try reading with `fread` from `data.table` i.e. `lapply(lfiles, fread)` and instead of having many columns, it may be better to `rbind` with a grouping variable, i.e. `rbindlist(lapply(lfiles, fread), idcol=TRUE)`  (though the post contains very little info to give any kind of solution)

Comment: are you looking to `cbind` or `rbind`? `rbindlist` from `data.table` is very fast

Comment: @Chris am trying column binding - `cbind`.

Comment: @akrun there are different types of files that I am trying to concatenate, I was just trying to figure out the best way to concatenate large number of files by columns.

Comment: @akrun I would like to accept your comment as answer - can you move it to an answer?

Comment: @KomalRathi  Thanks, posted that as an answer.

Comment: I wonder whether it's worth looking in to the Unix [paste function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910057/how-to-paste-columns-from-separate-files-using-bash) ...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For fast reading of files, we can use `fread` from `data.table` and then `rbind` the `list` of `data.table` using `rbindlist` specifying the `idcol=TRUE` to provide a grouping variable to identify each of the datasets

```
library(data.table)
DT <- rbindlist(lapply(lfiles, fread), idcol=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have all numerical data, you can convert to matrix first, which can be quite a bit faster than data frames:

```
> microbenchmark(
do.call(cbind, rep(list(sleep), 1000)),
do.call(cbind, rep(list(as.matrix(sleep)), 1000))
)
Unit: microseconds
                                              expr      min       lq       mean
            do.call(cbind, rep(list(sleep), 1000)) 6978.635 7496.690 8038.21531
 do.call(cbind, rep(list(as.matrix(sleep)), 1000))  636.282  722.814  862.01125
   median        uq       max neval
 7864.180 8397.8595 12213.473   100
  744.647  793.0695  7416.430   100
```

Alternatively, if you want a data frame, you can cheat by using `unlist` and then setting the class manually:

```
df <- unlist(rep(list(sleep), 1000), recursive=FALSE)
class(df) <- 'data.frame'
```