# Using bash to get Two variables in for-loop form two different lists

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop

I'm working with bash and I have two lists:

- `AZU SJI IOP`
- `A1 B1 C1`

Using the bash code below:

```
for f1 in AZU SJI IOP
do
    for f2 in A1 B1 C1
    do
        echo $f1 + $f2
    done
done
```

I get this result:

```
$ bash dir.sh
AZU + A1
AZU + B1
AZU + C1
SJI + A1
SJI + B1
SJI + C1
IOP + A1
IOP + B1
IOP + C1
```

I would like to get the result in this way

```
AZU A1

SJI B1

IOP C1
```

Comment: From [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): "_**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question_"

Comment: you want three resulting lines, so don't use two nested for loops or you'll have 3*3=9. Use one for loop iterating over 0 to 2, then use that number to index both lists. Moreover you've seen that `+` isn't a concatenation operator and will appear in the output, so just avoid it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [zip columns from separate files together in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036008/zip-columns-from-separate-files-together-in-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define two arrays such that they have the same indices, then iterate over the indices of one array:

```
list1=(AZU SJI IOP)
list2=(A1 B1 C1)

for i in "${!list1[@]}"; do
  echo "${list1[i]} ${list2[i]}"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You could of course use `paste`, but since your *lists* are not in files, you might be interested in a solution without external commands:

```
set -- A1 B1 C1
for f1 in AZU SJI IOP
do  echo $f1 $1
    shift
done
```